# How to allocate two-pointer to Struct?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have this code:

```
struct human
    {
        string name;
        string adress;
        string com_name;
        string com_adress;
    };
    human **arr_human;
```

I need to allocate array of pointers. 
I try it this:

```
arr_human = new human * [ 1000 ];
```

but I can't use this struct( example:

```
arr_human[0]->name = oName;
arr_human[0]->adress = oAddr;
arr_human[0]->com_name = cName;
arr_human[0]->com_adress = cAddr;
```

Why?

Comment: You've only allocated pointers, but not the objects they're supposed to point to. `for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) arr_human[i] = new human;`

Comment: And anyway... `std::vector<human> vec; vec.resize(1000);`

Answer (score 3):

Like jrok said, you allocated the pointers but not the objects. You probably want to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    arr_human[i] = new human[numObjectsYouWant];
```

Since you're using C++, you might as well use vectors though. Does away with many of the problems you might encounter with using raw pointers.

```
vector<human> arr_humans;
```